# OpenLayer adjust circle radius during zoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I saw many questions but none of them works with me.

I create some circles in a loop.

```
 var coordenada = ol.proj.fromLonLat([coordenada_y , coordenada_x]);
 coordenada_x = parseFloat(coordenada_x);
 coordenada_y = parseFloat(coordenada_y);
 incradius = incradius * 0.0001;
 var circle = new ol.geom.Circle([coordenada_y, coordenada_x], incradius);
 console.log(incradius);
 circle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:4326');  

 var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);
 circleFeature.setProperties({
 originalZoom: zoom,
 });

 var circleStyle = new Style({
 fill: new Fill({ color: '#ffdc0080' }),
 stroke: new Stroke({ color: '#e6c70050', width: 5 })
 });
 circleFeature.setStyle(circleStyle);                       
 vector.push(circleFeature);
```

This draws the circles with a radius I calculate for each circle

But this makes the circles radius static so they won't adjust when zoom.

I made then in the wheel listener this:

```
function updateCircleSize(previousZoom, zoom) {

var vectorSource = vectorLayer.getSource();
var features = vectorSource.getFeatures();
var scale = 0.01;
var newRadius = 0;
// Eliminar los círculos existentes
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  var feature = features[i];
  vectorSource.removeFeature(feature);
}

// Crear y agregar los nuevos círculos con el tamaño actualizado
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  var originalFeature = features[i];
  var originalGeometry = originalFeature.getGeometry();
  var originalCenter = originalGeometry.getCenter();
  var originalRadius = originalGeometry.getRadius();

  var originalStyle = originalFeature.getStyle();
  var originalFill = originalStyle.getFill();
  var originalStroke = originalStyle.getStroke();

// Calcular el factor de ajuste del zoom según la dirección del zoom
 if (zoom >= previousZoom) {

    newRadius = (originalRadius / 1.5); // Factor de ajuste para acercarse (hacer más pequeño)
  
} else if (zoom < previousZoom) {
    newRadius = (originalRadius * 2) ; // Factor de ajuste para alejarse (hacer más grande)    
}
newRadius = newRadius;


var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(originalCenter, newRadius);
circle.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:4326');

var circleFeature = new ol.Feature(circle);

var circleStyle = new Style({
  fill: originalFill,
  stroke: originalStroke
});

circleFeature.setStyle(circleStyle);

// Agregar el nuevo feature al vector source
vectorSource.addFeature(circleFeature);
```

}

So everytime the user zooms it deletes all circles and create them again with the new radius, this works but the result is weird because when the circle are big the multiplication creates very big circles.

Moreover I have another function when the user clicks and the map set in that point with a specific zoom and the circle is drawn with the last radius calculated, so the result is a very big circle again.

Could you tell me how can I do this please?

Comment: It might be easier to use a Point geometry and Circle style as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

You can control the attributes (and the radius) how you want with a style function. A style function is called on every feature whenever they are re-rendered, so when you pan map, zoom etc...

```js
// Calculate the initial radius based on the current zoom level. Assuming you have a reference to the map object as 'map'var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  var newRadius = calculateRadiusBasedOnZoom(map.getView().getZoom())

  // Create the circle style with the calculated radius
  var circleStyle = new Style({
    image: new Circle({
      radius: radius,
      fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)' }),
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 2 })
    })
  });

  // Return the style for the feature
  return [circleStyle];
};
```

You can also set the radius based on an attribute:

```js
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  // Get the desired radius value from the feature's properties
  var radius = feature.get('myRadius');

  // Create the circle style with the specified radius
  var circleStyle = new Style({
    image: new Circle({
      radius: myRadius,
      fill: new Fill({ color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)' }),
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: 'red', width: 2 })
    })
  });

  // Return the style for the feature
  return [circleStyle];
};
```

And then you can set the `myRadius` on each individual circle feature:

```js
var newZoom = map.getView().getZoom();

// set a random radius on each circle based on zoom level
for (var feature of myCircleFeatures) {
  var randomNumber = Math.random();
  var newRadius = newZoom * randomNumber;
  feature.set("myRadius", newRadius);
}
```